# Angular material как вручную пометить поле не валидным (и перекрасить в красный) если в поле валидное значение

Tags: angular4, angular-material

Форма для регистрации, заполняются поля и отсылаются на сервер. Сервер присылает ответ что email уже занят. Тогда я хочу подсветить поле email как не валидное но при этом значение в этом поле поддерживает формат email и валидатором признается как валидным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал разные вариации

```
this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors({ invalid: true, valid: false })
```

но поле не подкрашивается. Как это сделать?

**registration.component.ts**

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  public registerForm: FormGroup
  public spinnerShow = false
  public errMsg: String
  public bothErrMsg: String.

  constructor(
    ...
    private matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<RegistrationComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [FormValidationService.emailValidator]],
      password: this.fb.group({
        pwd: ['', [FormValidationService.passwordValidator]],
        confirm: ['', [FormValidationService.passwordValidator]],
      }, {validator: FormValidationService.confirmValidator('pwd', 'confirm')}),
      username: ['', [FormValidationService.shortStringValidator]],
    })
  }

  register() {
    this.spinnerShow = !this.spinnerShow
    const regData = this.registerForm.value
    regData.confirm = this.registerForm.value.password.confirm
    regData.password = this.registerForm.value.password.pwd

    this.auth.registration(regData).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res.error) {
          this.spinnerShow = !this.spinnerShow
          const messages = res.messages
          for (const key in messages) {
            if (messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (key === 'both') {
                this.bothErrMsg = messages[key]
                this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors({ notUnique: true })
              } else {
                this.registerForm.controls[key].setErrors({ errMsg: messages[key] })
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          this.lc.setItem('user', res.user)
          this.matDialogRef.close()
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error) // TODO
        this.spinnerShow = !this.spinnerShow
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**registration.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Register new user.</h3>
  <form [formGroup]="registerForm" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.hasError('errMsg') && registerForm.controls.email.touched">
        {{ registerForm.get('email').getError('errMsg') }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="error" *ngIf="bothErrMsg !== undefined">{{ bothErrMsg }}</div>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid == true" (click)="register()">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ошибка от сервера (both это serverErrorMsg еще не переименовал в нормальное имя). Сервер возвращает код 200 и сообщение об ошибке если она есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте кастомную ошибку, и поставьте ее через `setErrors`, например  `this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors({ duplicate: true })`

Comment: А что значит кастомную ошибку? Про кастомный валидатор в курсе.

Comment: Ну, вот вы ошибку вот так ставите для control `this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors({ duplicate: true })`. И у вас будет этот control с ошибкой, форма не валидной, control будет подкрашиваться

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Попробовал но не помогло. Вывод console.log(this.registerForm) показывает что форма валидная, поля duplicate там вообще нет.

Comment: Поле `dupicate` будет здесь `this.registerForm.controls['email'].errors.duplicate` или `this.registerForm.controls['email'].hasError('duplicate')`. И покажите ваш актуальный код, где и как вы ставите `duplicate`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Добавил.

Comment: Спасибо за код, теперь немного лучше. Выглядит нормально. Теперь приведите пример `html` разметки и содержимое ответа от сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вы неправильно используете директиву `matInput`. Инпут автоматически подсвечивается если у контрола `errors !== null`. Вот вам простой пример:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
        <mat-error *ngIf="email.dirty && email.hasError('notUnique')">This email is already taken!</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

В компоненте достаточно того, что вы делаете внутри `subscribe`, только еще непонятно почему вы обрабатываете ошибки внутри `subscribe`, если сервер возвращает 422 (ошибка валидации), то это нужно обрабатывать внутри `onError` или с помощью оператора `catchError`:

```
public registerForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
    })
});

public get email(): AbstractControl {
    return this.registerForm.get('email')!;
}

public register(): void {
    this.auth.registration(this.registerForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.email.setErrors({ notUnique: true });
    });
}
```

Comment: Я обрабатываю ошибку внутри subscribe потому что сервер их возвращает с кодом 200.

Comment: @SergeiR, покажите полностью ваш компонент, вы используете `OnPush`?

Comment: Исправил, целиком html форму не стал вставлять.

Comment: и вы точно уверены, что дело доходит до условия `this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors`?

Comment: Ну по крайней мере console.log перед ним срабатывает. Да и сообщение this.bothErrMsg = messages[key] (This email is olready taken!) выводится.

Comment: у вас стоит `OnPush` или нет?

Comment: Нет у меня не стоит.

Comment: давайте будем идти от другого конца, дабы убедиться в том, что инпут не подсвечивает при регистрации, если вы просто в конструкторе диалогового окна сделаете `setTimeout(() => this.email.setErrors(...), 3000)` (как пример) - что-то произойдет или нет?

Comment: Я наверное задам тупой вопрос но конструктор диалогового окна это в registration.component.ts ? Но this.email (unused expression)

Comment: конструктор это `constructor`, диалоговое окно - это отдельный компонент, не `this.email`, а как вы обращаетесь к контролу `email` у себя, `this.form.controls.email....`

Comment: Поправил сверху свой registration.component.ts он и есть диалоговое окно для регистрации. И если в constructor писать setTimeout(() => this.registerForm.controls['email'].setErrors(...), 3000) то вообще ни чего не работает в консоли ReferenceError: ngOnInit is not defined. Если добавить таймаут в ngOnInit то поле все равно не подкрашивается.

Comment: Отправил вам на емайл.

Comment: Проблема была в том что скрывая форму *ngIf="!spinnerShow" Angular перерендерил view и обнулил все ошибки.